# I keep getting error 422 when trying to start process instance using REST API

Tags: rest, activiti, postman

I'm trying to use the REST API, from Postman REST client on Chrome.

Here's my screenshot:

[image]

I keep getting error 422: "The server understands the content type of the request entity and the syntax of the request entity is correct but was unable to process the contained instructions".

I'm using Activiti 5.16.3 on MacOS Maverick, with Java 1.8.

The process I tried to call is the one that comes with the demo of Activiti, Vacation Request.

The JSON payload in my request is:

```
{
    "processDefinitionKey":"vacationRequest",
    "variables":[
        {"name": "employeeName", "value": "Raka","type":"string"},
        {"name": "numberOfDays", "value": "5", "type":"integer"},
        {"name": "vacationMotivation", "value": "", "type":"string"},
        {"name": "startDate", "value": "01-01-2014 11:11", "type":"date"}
    ]
}
```

Oh, and I had to add a header "Content-Type" with its value set to "application/json" (otherwise I'd get error code 415: "The server is refusing to service the request because the entity of the request is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method").

What am I missing?

Btw, I need to be able to demonstrate the use of the REST API through tools like Postman. So, no Java code. It's because another programmer (front-end) will interact directly with Activiti bpm.

Thanks in advance for your help. This is really critical.

**
Additional comments:

1. I didn't have issue with other REST methods that are GET (for example: listing process definitions, etc). Looks like I'm only having trouble with POST (and maybe PUT too).
2. Not much info on this on google: https://www.google.com/search?as_q=rest+422&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=http%3A%2F%2Fforums.activiti.org&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=&gws_rd=ssl
3. I've tried also this suggestion. Didn't work for me: http://forums.activiti.org/comment/23039#comment-23039
   **

Best regards,
Raka

Answer (score 3):

Solved now....

Looks like there should be no whitespace between the opening { and the rest of the document.

Here's my screenshot:

[image]